# VM to Connect full screen for Hyper-V on Boot

Tags: hyper-v

We have some training machines (Windows Server 2008 r2) that we'd like to boot up and load the VM for the clients to use.

I thought it would be pretty simple via powershell, but so far. all i can do is get it to start up (Not connect).

doing searchs for connecting to VM obviously come up with random links to how to do a normal connect. Not load up the VM full screen mode if you log into the Hyper-V

Thanks for any help

S

Answer (score 1):

Use remote desktop for full screen with Hyper-V.